# Hazel cast client port issue

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using a hazelcast client to connect to a server on port 5710, but because the server is configured auto increment then sometimes the server takes port 5711 so the client will not be able to connect to the server, is there any other configuration instead of disabling the auto increment on the server

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
<port auto-increment=“false”>5701</port>
```

if you use `hazelcast.xml`.

Set

```
auto-increment: false
```

if you use `hazelcast.yaml`

Set

```
setPortAutoIncrement(false)
```

if you configure the servers from Java.

Probably worth finding out why 5701 is in use.

Hazelcast by default will try port 5701, and if this is use try 5702, then 5703...  (unless the auto-increment flag is set).

If you get as far as 5711 then lots of ports are already in use, which is probably your real problem.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a solution without setting the auto increment to false on the server @Neil.

Comment: Whatever is on port 5710 is I presume not joining to the Hazelcast server on 5711. It's likely but not certain what is using 5710 is a Hazelcast server, but if it's not joining to the one on 5711 it could be because they have different group name/password. That would be worth finding out. If you fix that you don't need the `auto-increment`.